# Swift UITableview cells open its own webview

Tags: swift, uiwebview, tableview

In Swift, I am trying to have a UITableview with multiple table cells and each cell I want to open its own unique UIWebview. I know how to make a button open a web view in a different View Controller, but how do I link each unique table view cell to open its own unique web view in a different View Controller? Thanks so much for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use tableview delegate method 'didSelectRowatAtIndexpath' and map the datasource array which you are using to fill table view.